# How to fix this json error while creating a new angular 8 project

Tags: npm, angular8

i am facing this error, on visual studio code, immediately after having created a new angular 8 project:

```
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\stproject\my-app> npm install
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...eprecated"},"1.0.4":{'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-27T08_30_00_012Z-debug.log
```

The output is the above stated error, but this is wrong. The project should rather have been ready to be served using ng serve command.

kindly help....

Comment: You possibly have a syntax error on `package.son`.

Comment: can you elaborate your point? I didn't really get you.

Comment: Can you add a piece of your `package.json` please ? Where the error append

Comment: {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },

Comment: "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",

Comment: "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}

Comment: That's the code in package.json file

Comment: PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\stproject\my-app> npm install
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...eprecated"},"1.0.4":{'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-27T08_30_00_012Z-debug.log

Comment: and this is the error

Comment: @GursimranShah Add additional info on OP by using edit option.

Comment: What kind of additional information do you need?   Actually I have already explained the entire issue .So, I need to know that what else do you need to be able to solve this problem?